# Erase app data on iOS simulator or real devices

Tags: ios

I am developing natives apps for both Android and iOS and when debugging some login scenarios I need to reset the app to its initial stage without any token persisted on the (virtual) device. On Android, it is just as easy as typing an adb commande `adb shell pm clear my.app.package`.

Is there a way on iOS or shall I go through the lengthy process of uninstalling and re-installing the app ?

Answer (score 1):

On iOS, erase all content and settings is how you wipe everything and then push your app again.

```
xcrun whatever....
```

The above `xcrun` is just useful to install and run an app as opposed to what you want which is to manage settings. See this developer article - at the very end it explains your settings persist even with app removal - so you’d need to clean on the simulator or write your app to reset settings with specific code.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059i-CH6-SW5

How effective these three options is really depends on your specific code, however. Erase all content always works.

Comment: Thanks @bmike, I would like to understand from my mac command line `xcrun defaults delete com.my.app` will remove my app from the simulator of physical device attache via USB ? Can I mention a device name ? Did not found more than the --help short documentation

Comment: @PhilippeCohen xcrun only installs an app bundle from a script on the mac as opposed to clicking run in Xcode. It automates things you would click in Xcode - not that it opens an ssh / command line to do things. I’m going to revisit the uninstall option after digging up an Apple article explaining that won’t work

Comment: @bmike Please be aware that you two are talking about two vastly different things. bmike is talking about settings bundles, which is not what you want. The tokens in your app are not persisted in the settings bundle - so even though you could remove the settings bundle, it is not going to achieve what Philippe want.

Comment: Indeed @jksoegaard I am looking for a way to clean persistent storage created by my react-native app, using different means than setting bundle. In Android this is enabled both from the UI (Clear Storage) and from adb. I do not find any equivalent on iOS

Comment: Please describe where or how your app stores the tokens. Are you using AsyncStorage? Or using one of the modules that stores them in Keychain?

Comment: @jksoegaard feel free to make a major edit or post at the start of my answer to clarify. I appreaciate your insight. My info is very broad streak - everything goes out baby and bathwater if you erase all content and settings, etc... thank you for stepping up with critique and help.

Comment: @bmike I'll create a new answer when Phillippe supplies the necessary information. I'm an app developer myself and often need to do the same as Phillippe, but how you do it is entirely dependent on how the tokens are stored. However, no one stores tokens in settings bundles - so that's definitely not the way to go. Also "Erase all content and settings" doesn't work on the Simulator at all. On a real device it will delete the tokens ordinarily, but it is not a practical advice as you cannot really do that 20-30 times a day - and you wouldn't want to do it on a device you use for other things.

Comment: Does this need to head to stack overflow as well or is it on topic for how Xcode works and how iOS work in general? @jksoegaard

Comment: It has nothing to do with Xcode, nor is it a programming question. Seems perfectly on topic. You could say that it is just a coincidence that Philippe is also the app developer. It could be anyone else wanting to test an app, and afterwards make sure that any authentication token have been erased.